# Rails 3.1 Asset pipeline - Why my images do not precompile for production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

When running:

```
rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

Everything precompiles but not my `/app/assets/images/*`

I even tried adding this to my `environment/production.rb`

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images"
```

What's wrong? thanks!

Comment: Found a solution:
Add to `environment/production.rb`

    config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jp?g *.gif]

Why isn't this default ;ike this line says:
`(application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)`

Comment: *.jp?g doesn't work - the ? matches exactly 1 character as it's a glob match and not a regexp. What you want is `config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]`

Comment: Yup, i figured it out, thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, I thought I was having a similar problem, but after many hours learning a lot more details on how the asset pipeline works, I discovered that I just had a syntax error in the argument passed to my image_tag helper!  In Rails 3.2.8 at least, there was no need to change any of the defaults in the environment file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found a solution: `Add to environment/production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]
```

Why isn't this default ;ike this line says: (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)

Comment: *.jp?g doesn't work - the ? matches exactly 1 character as it's a glob match and not a regexp. What you want is `config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]`

Comment: Found this was an issue in Rails 4. When we moved our assets directory to /assets instead of /app/assets

Comment: Why the hell we should 'precompile' images? I don't see any sense in doing this

Comment: For anyone else coming here, in Rails 5 it should be `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)` in your `config/initializers/assets` folder

Comment: @divideByZero e.g. to add the md5 fingerprint, let's say you have some logo.png or default.png images, when you change them, their md5 hash will change as well, and the change in resulting URL to image will force the browser to fetch fresh copy (after change)

Answer (score 2):

Use this format for the server:

```
rails assets:precompile:all -e production
```

Comment: you mean `rake  assets:precompile:all` ?

Comment: Try `rails assets:precompile -e production'

Comment: don't need to specify environment with `assets:precompile` it's production by default

Comment: A quick note: rake assets:precompile:all doesn't generate the hashed (fingerprinted) versions of my assets. For that reason, I returned to using just rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 0):

In my case some **incompatible gem** was using something along the lines:

```
config.assets.precompile << %r(bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/[\w-]+\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff2?)$)
```

Removing the gem, or updating it could fix the issue.
**This is because the gem was made for older Rails version**.

That wasn't clear directly from the console output.

For my case, as updating the gem wasn't possible at the time being, the solution was to remove the problematic asset path, by adding in `application.rb` due to compatibility:

```
config.after_initialize do
    bootstrap_index = config.assets.precompile.index(/bootstrap\/glyphicons-halflings-regular\.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff2?)$/)
    config.assets.precompile.delete_at(bootstrap_index)
end
```

And adding missing file that should be precompiled to:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .woff2)
```